# Using a variable inside a string

Tags: python, blender, literals

I am facing a problem while trying to assign materials "on the go" to a set of cubes in Blender3D. I know it comes from the fact that the objects data names are being incremented when generated (Cube, Cube.001, cube.002...) but I don't know the way to have the name of the object being interactive with the loop. I'd really appreciate if someone could give me a tip !!

```
Dark = bpy.data.materials['Dark']
Light= bpy.data.materials['Light']
for x in range(4):
    for y in range(4):
        for z in range(4):
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_add_cube(radius=.049, location=(x,y,z))
            a = bpy.data.object['Cube']
            if (x+y+z) % 2 == 0:
                a.data.materials.append(Dark)
            else:
                a.data.materials.append(Light)
```

Comment: You can certainly just use `bpy.data.object['Cube{}{}{}'.format(x, y, z)]` or `bpy.data.object['Cube%s%s%s' % (x, y, z)]` for python 2.x.

Comment: Assuming 001 comes from x=0, y=0, z=1. However, does primitive_add_cube not return the cube it creates? I couldn't find any documentation of that function in the blender docs

Comment: Yes it would produce 64 cubes, but no not 000 to 064. It would go from 000 to 333. But your code only create 64 cubes, assuming these cubes are created by primitive_add_cube.

Comment: You mentioned primitive_add_cube returns a set, a set of what?

Comment: It wouldn't work as 3 iterations of 4 produces 64 cubes: from 'Cube' to 'Cube.063'. I would create a new variable 'A = x*y*z' and it would be tested by a 'if A = 0' then 'A = NULL' so that we have no interference with the first object which is named 'Cube' and not 'Cube.000'. Then we need to use this variable 'A' to fill the lists but how ?

Comment: It is an object of type 'set' as in 'set-up'

Comment: A python 'set' contains objects, it's like a list. Are you trying to fill a dictionary or retrieve values that are already stored in one? I'm confused

Comment: Well I haven't really changed the code as it appears in the original question. What I am trying to achieve is assigning the created Cubes as they come to creation in the loop to a variable so that I can then assign them a material. The primitive_add_cube() is a function that is used to create geometry in the software. It is not an object. Right ?

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought you were trying to do. Yes, primitive_add_cube looks like a function that creates a geometric object, but most functions return something and it would make sense for a function like that to return the object it created, in one form or another